# What is value of k in next hermonic serie?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to know the value of k such that $\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n} \geq 8000$. Thanks.

Comment: Almost all positive integer values of $k$ will work.  Please be more specific about what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H_k=\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n}$ is a [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), and it is known that $$H_k\approx \ln k$$
so if you want $$\ln k \ge 8000$$ you will want $$k\ge e^{8000}$$
This is a number with almost 3500 decimal digits.

Comment: You need to be more precise in how $H_k \sim \ln(k)$ to say that $k \geq e^{8000}$. Indeed, you can show that $ \ln(k) + \gamma \leq H_k \leq  \ln(k) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2k}$. so it's more $k \geq e^{8000-\gamma}$. Even if this doesn't change the order of $k$, it divide the value of $k$ you found by around $1.78$